# how to remove translation error in apertium language pair?

Tags: nlp, apertium

i m translating words in terminal by this command 
`echo باپ | apertium -d . urd-pan_Arab` 
 and it is giving me  
#پیو 
which is correct but when i run 
 `echo کبھی | apertium -d . urd-pan_Arab` 
it is giving me same word again as if there is no word in dict file 
 *کبھی 
instead of  #کدی

 this is repository (https://github.com/hsumerf/apertium-urd-pan) and words are on line no. 266 & 267 in file  **apertium-urd-pan/apertium-urd-pan.urd-pan_Arab.dix** , how to overcome this problem?

Comment: If you get a `#`, try `echo کبھی | apertium -d . urd-pan_Arab-dgen`  – it should also give you the "debug" output of the generator, showing what the generator tried to generate. Try also `urd-pan_Arab-postchunk` which is the input to the generator, or `ls modes` to show all such debug modes.

Comment: sorry i didnt get `urd-pan_Arab-postchunk` and ls `modes` ,what are these?

Comment: after `echo باپ | apertium -d . urd-pan_Arab-postchunk` i got 
`^پیو<n><m><sg><nom>$^.<sent>$` but what is `$^.<sent>$` ?

Answer (score 3):

In the `apertium-urd` dictionary, کبھی is an adverb, in the `apertium-urd-pan` dictionary it is a masculine noun. As the tags don't match the word is not added to the final transducer.

To fix this, either add کبھی as an adverb to the bilingual dictionary or add کبھی as a masculine noun to the Urdu monolingual dictionary.

Comment: so should I check all words in urdu dictionary? and what will be the best way to check all words?